# How to prevent a drain cover from being a trip hazard

Tags: drain, safety

There is a raised drain cover in a communal garden which has been highlighted as a trip hazard.
I can't lower it as the surrounding earth will eventually cover it and we need access to it in an emergency but we need to make it clear to others that it is there but obviously boxing over it will make more of a hazard!
Any ideas on how to highlight this as a hazard without making it worse?!

Comment: Three or four decent looking posts with plastic or metal chain between them(check for pipes underground if digging), small planter on a stand with cover as base.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have three broad options:

- Keep the path; eliminate the hazard. Reduce the height of the drain cover so that it is flush to the surrounding surface. You might make the cover much larger (surface area), and perhaps choose or make a cover that has no perforations within a few inches of its edges, to avoid the twin problems of the cover being covered by soil or sediment falling into the drain.
- Keep the path; transform the hazard. Replace the drain cover with a length of pipe rising vertically, waist-high to a person or higher, to transform the "trip" hazard into a less likely and less hazardous "walked-into-a-post" situation. Perforate the base of the pipe so that surface water can flow into it.
- Move the path; now the drain as-is is not a hazard. Erect some kind of barrier around the drain. It might take the form of a fence, a decorative feature like a park bench, a flower pot or other planter with elevated base standing above the drain, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Place somthing large, but portable, on top of it so that none considers walking over it.  bird-bath, planter, sundial, barbecue, sculpture, whatever.

Paint it orange and black stripes so that everyone sees it.

Raise the ground around it with pavers etc.

fence it off.